# How do I get a particle system to generate meshes for polygon hair?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I've been searching for an answer for quite a long time now but I haven't found the solution yet.. My problem is that I'd like to use Cycles' hair particle system to generate meshes (in my case planes, which have fur textures on them) instead of Blender's hair thingy.

I'm trying to optimize my mesh as much as I can, because it's going to be used in a game engine.

So what I'm trying to achieve is kinda something like this in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Wi4-fdeYyM

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hmm, maybe create multiple hair planes with textures, add them to a group, and then use the group as an object set in the hair (instead of hair, you can set it to use objects)?

Comment: The particle system doesn't generate meshes for hair, You generate the meshes for hair, the particle system only distributes them for you. Model a simple plane like the one shown in the tutorial, apply a hair texture to it, then use a non-hair particle system to distribute it over your character

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos a non-hair particle system?

Comment: Yes, you can change between the two after adding to object, see the Blender manual about [Particle Systems](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/introduction.html#types-of-particle-systems) there are *Hair* and *Emitter* types

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thx for the link, but I still am surprised because you can use the hair particle system with object replacement just fine. And in this case you will have to, as physics will take action over the emitted mesh objects.

Comment: No, you'd want to keep it a hair particle system, you just want to change the display type. You generally use hair for anything that is supposed to stick to a surface.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around and it looks like my previous thoughts were taking me to the right direction, except I forgot to do something.

Like Gliderman said, creating a group out of multiple hair textures works, and even if you just add them as an object.

[image: Adding it as an object]

[image: Adding them as a group]

By doing this, and the reason why I was so unsure in my steps is because when you add them you get something like this, instead of the nice hair.

[image: Without velocity]

What you have to do this, play around with the velocity (ye right, this is so trivial, but somehow so managable to not be cared of..).

After turning up velocity's Emitter Object's values, you get closer to your desired results:

[image: Velocity]
[image: Finalish result]

Comment: How about a render?